# How do I make an conditional offset in gnuplot?

Tags: label, conditional-statements, gnuplot, offset

I have a new question about gnuplot. I have columns and sometimes there is place for a value in the column and sometimes not. Is it possible to make the offset of the label text conditional, see example with the white values?

[image: part of gnuplot graphics]

I tried with:

```
"<tail -60 p1_en_gr2.txt" u 1:11:($11>0 ? $11 : sprintf("")) w labels left rotate font ",10" tc rgb "#00b900" ($11>250 ? offset 0 : offset -2) notitle,\
```

This is not working. Is there a trick for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not possible this way. But you can write

```
..u 1:11:($11>250 ? $11 : sprintf("")) w labels left rotate font ",10" tc rgb "#00b900" offset 0 notitle,
'' u 1:11:(($11<250 && $11>0)? $11 : sprintf("")) w labels left rotate font ",10" tc rgb "#00b900" offset -2 notitle,\
...
```

So you split it in one plot for values 0...250 and one plot for larger values.